# Including a href and php variable in Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send emails, my problem is that I'm trying to send a link in the email, but the link doesn't work and it's in plain text in the message, here is my code:

```
$message = (new Swift_Message('Visit us'))
          ->setFrom(['info@example.com' => 'info@example.com'])
          ->setTo(['info@example.com' => 'info@example.com'])
          ->setBody('<html><body>
          <p">Please visit us: </p>
          <br>
          <p><a href = "https://www.google.com?ticket='.$ticket.'">visit us</a></p>
          </body></html>',
                   'text/html')
          ;
```

As I said the link doesn't work in the email, even without the $ticket variable

Comment: `<p">Please visit` – what’s with that `"` there?

Comment: Sorry for that, I removed it and still the link doesn't work

Comment: _“and it's in plain text in the message”_ - meaning what, exactly? Does it show the _tags_ for all of the HTML elements? Or does most of the HTML get parsed and displayed as expected, and only the link somehow not? Have you checked what the generated HTML code inside the mail body looked like?

Comment: Yes, I checked and found that it only shows "<p>visit us</p>" without the "<a></a>" tag, the html is displayed as expected except the <a> tag

Comment: Still can’t tell whether you are talking about the HTML _source code_, or the rendered view now.

Comment: It's displayed and rendered fine, but there is no link.. and when I check the Inspect mode.. there's no <a> tag at all, only the <p> tag.

Comment: And _where_ are you looking at this? Desktop mail client, web mailer interface, …?

Comment: web mail interface and mobile mail client

Comment: What is the actual recipient address? Could this be some freemail provider filtering out parts of the message perhaps, because it thinks they are spammy.

Comment: I just changed the recipient address in the question for privacy reasons, in the real message I'm using my address

Comment: Saying “my address” doesn’t answer the question, whether this is an account with some free mail provider, or whether you are talking about a mail account hosted under your own domain. Have you tried sending to a different recipient yet, whether that changes anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried with other addresses but the same thing happened,